# Error at using Laravel Eloquent's orWhere() and orWhereHas()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I am working on a function to search for students and their pick-up parents.

The response Json will look like this:

```
{
  "student_id": 1159,
  "full_name": "Student Test IT2",
  "student_code": "HSTESTIT2",
  "family_code": "No code",
  "gender": 0,
  "student_pick_up": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 985,
        "first_name": "Father",
        "last_name": "Test IT",
        "full_name": "Father Test IT",
        "parent_code": null,
        "phone_numbers": [
          {
            "id": 681,
            "country_code": "VN",
            "phone_code": 84,
            "number": "62594283",
            "pick_up_id": 985,
            "is_primary": 1,
            "created_at": "2023-07-16T03:35:51.000000Z",
            "updated_at": null,
            "deleted_at": null
          }
        ],
        "identity_card_number": "444343",
        "is_long_term": 0,
        "start_date": null,
        "end_date": null,
        "gender": null,
        "is_representative": 0,
        "is_enable": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 991,
        "first_name": "Mother",
        "last_name": "Test IT",
        "full_name": "Mother Test IT",
        "parent_code": null,
        "phone_numbers": [],
        "identity_card_number": null,
        "is_long_term": 0,
        "start_date": null,
        "end_date": null,
        "gender": null,
        "is_representative": 0,
        "is_enable": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is the code for that function

```
$filter = $request->get('input');

return $this->repository
            ->with(['classes' => $classes])
            ->whereHas('classes', $classes)
            ->with(['studentPickUp' => function ($query) use ($branchId, $currentDateTime) {
                $query->where('branch_id', $branchId);
                $query->where('is_effect', IsEffect::Effective->value);
                $query->where(function ($subQuery) use ($currentDateTime) {
                    $subQuery->where('is_long_term', IsLongIterm::Indefinite->value)
                    ->orWhere(function ($subQuery) use ($currentDateTime) {
                        $subQuery->where('start_date', '<=', $currentDateTime);
                        $subQuery->where('end_date', '>=', $currentDateTime);
                    });
                });
            },'studentPickUp.pickUp', 'studentPickUp.involvedType' => function ($query) {
                $query->select(['id', 'name', 'code']);
            },
            ])
            ->whereHas('studentPickUp', function ($query) use ($branchId) {
                $query->where('branch_id', $branchId);
            })
            ->when(is_string($filter) && $filter, function ($q) use ($lang, $filter, $studentRepresentativeIds) {
                $q->where(function ($query) use ($lang, $filter, $studentRepresentativeIds) {
                    $query->where(DB::raw("CAST(students.full_name->>'$.$lang' AS CHAR)"), 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')
                        ->orWhere(DB::raw('lower(students.student_code)'), 'like', '%' . strtolower($filter) . '%')
                        ->orWhereHas('studentPickUp', function ($query) use ($filter, $lang, $studentRepresentativeIds) {
                            $query->where('is_active', StudentPickUpStatus::ACTIVE->value)
                                ->where(function ($query) use ($filter, $lang, $studentRepresentativeIds) {
                                    $query->whereHas('studentPickUpPhoneNumbers', function ($builder) use ($filter) {
                                        $builder->where(DB::raw("LOCATE('$filter', student_pick_up_phone_numbers.number)"), '>', 0)
                                            ->where('student_pick_up_phone_numbers.is_primary', StudentPickUpPhoneNumber::IS_PRIMARY->value);
                                    })->orWhere(DB::raw("CAST(student_pick_up.full_name->>'$.$lang' AS CHAR)"), 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')
                                        ->orWhere(DB::raw("LOCATE('$filter', student_pick_up.identitycard_number)"), '>', 0)
                                        ->when(!empty($studentRepresentativeIds), function ($q) use ($studentRepresentativeIds) {
                                            $q->orWhereIn('student_representative_id', $studentRepresentativeIds);
                                        });
                                });
                        });
                });
            })
            ->orderBy($orderBy, $sortedBy)->paginate($request->get('limit') ?? 10);
```

The bug I'm facing is when the input of `$filter` like `students.full_name`(Student Test IT2), it will return correct response.

But when i inpu `62594283`, which like the `student_pick_up_phone_numbers.number`, or `444343` of `identity_card_number`. It only null return.

Here is my model relationship

```
class StudentBase extends ParentModel
{
    use HasTranslations;

    protected $table = 'students';

    public function studentPickUp(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StudentPickUp::class, 'student_id');
    }
}
```

```
class StudentPickUpBase extends ParentModel
{
    use HasTranslations;

    public array $translatable = ['full_name', 'student_name', 'class_name'];

    public function studentPickUpPhoneNumbers(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StudentPickUpPhoneNumber::class, 'pick_up_id');
    }
}
```

I want to return all results wherever one of the three properties below is the same as $filter (full_name, phone number or identity card)

Answer (score 0):

- you can utilize a combination of 'where' and 'orWhere' clauses to search across different fields. Also, you might want to use the 'orWhereHas' method to search within the relationships.

  ```
  return $this->repository
      // Your existing code 

      ->when(is_string($filter) && $filter, function ($q) use ($lang, $filter, $studentRepresentativeIds) {
          $q->where(function ($query) use ($lang, $filter, $studentRepresentativeIds) {
              // Your existing code 
              $query->orWhereHas('studentPickUp.studentPickUpPhoneNumbers', function ($builder) use ($filter) {
                  $builder->where('number', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')
                      ->where('is_primary', StudentPickUpPhoneNumber::IS_PRIMARY->value);
              })->orWhere('studentPickUp.full_name->>' . $lang, 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')
                  ->orWhere('studentPickUp.identitycard_number', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')
                  ->when(!empty($studentRepresentativeIds), function ($q) use ($studentRepresentativeIds) {
                      $q->orWhereIn('student_representative_id', $studentRepresentativeIds);
                  });
          });
      })
      // Your existing code 
      ->paginate($request->get('limit') ?? 10);
  ```
- This modification includes an 'orWhereHas' clause to search within the 'studentPickUpPhoneNumbers' relationship. Ensure that your relationships and table names are correctly represented in the Eloquent models.
- Make sure to adjust the column names and relationships based on your actual database structure and Eloquent model definitions.

Comment: thank you but it's not working, i have to remove `->orWhere('studentPickUp.full_name->>' . $lang, 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')` 

and `studentPickUp` at `studentPickUp.studentPickUpPhoneNumbers` to not get the error `Call to undefined method StudentPickUp::studentPickUp()"`